# Porting parseUnsignedInt to java1.7

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

I was using java1.8 which has `parseUnsignedInt()`. I was told that we have to use `java1.7` since that is on the system. I thought I could just port the `java.lang.Interger.java`, `java.lang.Long.java` and `java.lang.annotation.Native.java` functions and compile with my code. This allowed the code to compile without errors. When I run I get the following error:

> **Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Integer.parseUnsignedInt(Ljava/lang/String;)I**

The eclipse debugger can't seem to find the function either. What do I have to do to get this working?

Comment: I doubt you installed it in the proper jar file within the proper package.  It is picking  your JDK version.  It may be an import problem.  If you can't get it to work it would be easier to just write your own utility methods to accomplish that requirement.  Parsing `integers` and `longs` is not that difficult.

Comment: You're trying to override core `java.lang` libraries?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to override the java.lang libraries by compiling version of Integer.java, Long.java and annotation/Native.java in the src directory java/lang of my project. As stated I took the code from 1.8 for these files and basically placed them into my project (as answer 1 suggests) so the compile is correct but at runtime it cannot find them, thus the error above. I just need to figure out how to get the class files in my java\lang to be used instead of whats in the JRE library since 1.7 does not have the parseUnsignedInt() function.

Comment: you cannot add your own Integer class in the java.lang package because of JDK protection mechanisms. You have to write it in your own class, e.g. as a static method, and change all invokations.

Comment: Ah, yes I see. I tried renaming it to not cause interference with the Integer package and I got that error. Ok. I'll put it in my base function  so as to change the code in the least possible way and ripe it out when we go to java1.8 in a year or so...Thanks.

Comment: You might be better off with a simple, easy to understand, maintainable solution, like `long l = Long.parseLong(string);  if(l < 0 || l >= 1L<<32) throw new IllegalArgumentException();  int result = (int) l;` instead of copying the JDK code…

Answer (score 1):

The method parseUnsignedInt was introduced with Java 1.8, as it is documented in its javadoc (mind the **@since 1.8**):

```
/**
 * Parses the string argument as an unsigned decimal integer. The
 * characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except
 * that the first character may be an an ASCII plus sign {@code
 * '+'} ({@code '\u005Cu002B'}). The resulting integer value
 * is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were
 * given as arguments to the {@link
 * #parseUnsignedInt(java.lang.String, int)} method.
 *
 * @param s   a {@code String} containing the unsigned {@code int}
 *            representation to be parsed
 * @return    the unsigned integer value represented by the argument in decimal.
 * @throws    NumberFormatException  if the string does not contain a
 *            parsable unsigned integer.
 * @since 1.8
 */
public static int parseUnsignedInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return parseUnsignedInt(s, 10);
}
```

But the JDK also contains the sources, so you could write your own parseUnsignedInt method in your own class, similar to the implementation contained in Java 8 if the Java 8 license allows that.

See http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java
Line 661 ff

For details about security (i.e. why you can't place your own Integer class in java.lang package), option to overrule this security, and a reason why you should not (or better - why you are not allowed to), see selected answer in [Why I am able to re-create java.lang package and classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116767/why-i-am-able-to-re-create-java-lang-package-and-classes)

So, you will have to implement your own class in your own package:

```
package com.yourname;

/*
 * Contains code from OpenJDK Java8, Copyright (c) 1994, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * TODO add more info from Oracle class comment here.
 */
public class IntCompatUtilities {

    public static int parseUnsignedInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
        return parseUnsignedInt(s,10);
    }

    public static int parseUnsignedInt(String s, int radix)
                throws NumberFormatException {

        //TODO content from OpenJDK 8's Integer.parseUnsignedInt(String,int) here.
        //instead of return parseInt(s, radix); change to return Integer.parseInt(s, radix);
        //instead of throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s); throw new NumberFormatException(...)
   }
}
```

And then, let all your callers call `com.yourname.IntCompatUtilities.parseUnsignedInt(...)`

Comment: Thank you for the reference. This is what I have done and it didn't work completely. It allowed to compile but was not runnable.

Comment: Re-phrased my answer (added detailled instruction what to do).